# Is it guaranteed that division by power of 10 gives accurate result in Floating-point arithmetic standard)?

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

I found out that `9 * 0.0001 = 0.0009000000000000001`, but `9 / 10_000 = 0.0009`

Is it guaranteed that when you divide by power of 10 you will receive exact value (by IEEE 754-2019: IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic)

I am expecting someone who knows specific behavior of Floating-point standard to explain if there is such guarantees or not.

Comment: Nothing in that spec guarantees you will get an exact value.

Comment: No, it's not possible to guarantee it. 1 / 10 = 0.1 can't be represented by IEEE 754 format and therefore always contains a rounding error. You can test it with a tool like https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html Enter `0.1` and see what value actually is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.009 cannot be represented precisely by IEEE 754 floating point. The binary representation of 0.009 would be:

```
0.0000001001001101110100101111000110101001111110111110011101101100100010110100001110010101100000010000011
     0001001001101110100101111000110101001111110111110011101101100100010110100001110010101100000010000011
     ...
```

It is a rational number with an infinite number of (binary) digits after the decimal point.

So this cannot be represented in floating point which only has a finite number of binary digits available in the mantissa part.

0.009 in floating point is represented as follows:

```
sign exponent    mantissa
0    01111000    00100110111010010111100
```

But as the binary sequence is finite here, it actually represents this number:

0.0089999996125698089599609375....

A similar deviation will occur for other positive powers of 10 in 9/10<sup>n</sup>

You can make the conversion using [this tool](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).